# Link tag with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble getting a link tag with a variable to work. I tried wrapping an a `href` tag around the div but it keeps throwing errors at me. This is the code that works, I am trying to make `result.response.docs["0"].web_url` a link

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result) {
   $(".articles").append("<div id=link>" + result.response.docs["0"].web_url + "</div>");
}).fail(function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: What are the errors? Please show the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result) {
   $(".articles").append("<div id=link><a href='" + result.response.docs["0"].web_url + "'>Click me if you dare</a></div>");
}).fail(function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: The quotes were what was messing me up!

Comment: Yes it can be tricky sometimes :) if you want to use the same type of quotes you can escape them with backlash too if you want, like this: "\"\""